# Is there a reason GaN chargers stop at 65W?

Tags: charger

During the last year or so we have seen commercial release of USB chargers utilizing GaN technology. For some reason it seems no products go higher than 65W. The [Navitas reference platform](https://www.navitassemi.com/navitas-gan-power-ics-enable-worlds-smallest-65w-usb-pd-laptop-adapter/) was 65W, Delta released a 65W under the Innergie brand -- but nothing higher. Is there a technology reason for this? USB C goes up to 100W and 87W is reasonably popular because Apple shipped some of their MacBooks with such and so it's easier to market those as replacement.

Comment: If everything has the same specification as the reference platform, then everyone is just *copying* the reference platform.

Comment: Not Innergie, that's for sure because their solution _predates_ the Navitas reference... but the answer given looks the correct one. And I have no idea how "opinions" enter into this but that's Stackexchange for you.

Comment: Probably because the USB spec stops there

Comment: Please read my post: USB C goes up to 100W.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the input power of the adapter is less than 75W, you don't need a power factor correction stage (by EU and other regulations).

So they are easier to design, and they hit the largest segment of the market.

Once you need a 2 stage converter you have additional components and thermal considerations and GAN probably doesn't make as big a performance and size difference as it does with a single stage converter.

There are single stage PFC converters, but they suffer from various performance issues.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I wanted to know! I looked up the source of this  and the [PFC Harmonic Current Emissions – Guide to EN61000-3-2:2014](http://www.epsma.org/PFC%20Guide_03032018%20(3)%20final%207-7.pdf) has this to say: EN 61000-3-2:2014 ... doesn't apply to ... Non-lighting equipment with rated power of 75W or less.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing about the GaN designs prevent it from going past 65W. Navitas released a reference design before or about the same time for a GaN 150W AC-DC adapter (with a 100 to 500W target range) only it was targeted at a different market segment, high end laptops and televisions. https://www.navitassemi.com/navitas-gan-power-ics-enable-smallest-power-adapters-ultra-thin-tvs-laptops/

They even mention it in the link to provided.

The 65W reference design is a end product restraint. They chose a target power density per cc and worked backwards from there. A slightly larger or changed design would allow greater power at the cost of size and money. The 150W design uses a different topology and is more brick size instead of a cell phone cube sized charger. Less to do about engineering restrictions and more to do about marketing goals.